# How to edit response in jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for Service Call.I am getting response in xml format.With xml response, I am also getting title above it which is not part of the xml response.Below is the response i am getting

TOKEN

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <URL>https://link.com</URL>
    <ToName>sharnell Kkqwjidzwh</ToName>
    <Link>gsajfgasgfgasjkgfjasgfjgjg</Link>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the value of Link attribute.I tried this path in xpath extractor..

**//Link**
But it isnt working.I think it is because of TOKEN title at top of response.Do anyone one know how we can edit the response and remove that title from response.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: TOKEN text is included in the xml response it is written just above where xml response is starting.Thanks Shashank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all try checking `Use Tidy` box, it may help in case of non-valid XML/XTML

If it doesn't help - see below workaround:

If you need to strip off everything before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line you can do it via [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor).

1. Add a Beanshell PostProcessor **as a child** of the request which returns your TOKEN and XML
2. Make sure that Beanshell PostProcessor is **before** the XPath Extractor
3. Put the following code into Beanshell PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String originalResponse = new String(data);
   String filteredResponse = originalResponse.substring(originalResponse.indexOf("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"));
   prev.setResponseData(filteredResponse.getBytes());
   ```

The above code will override the response and cut everything which is before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line

Explanations:

- `data` - is byte array containing parent sampler's response data
- `substring` and `indexOf` - are basic [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods
- `prev` is an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class which provides read/write access to parent sampler's result

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks!!Its working.Do you have any idea on how to edit the value of "Link" attribute i have fetched as i don't want full of it.

Comment: [XPath Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) function may be what you're looking for